# Selection bias estimation in feedback loops

Tags: machine-learning, bias, bias-correction

I'm trying to design a feedback loop for improving logistic regression model over time, it consists of following steps:

- a user submits text for analysis;
- back-end system (model) runs multilabel logistic regression (among N labels) and choose M labels that have met threshold;
- labels are shown to the user and user can do 3 things with each prediction: agree/disagree and do nothing
- data then stored and used as a training set for improving models (with the initial weight used from the previous model)

This schema introduces selection bias and response bias:

- selection bias - training data distribution doesn't represent the original distribution
- response bias - users might agree to some labels more likely than to another;

So given this scheme, is there a way to take into account those biases and make updates to the model with normalized weights? 
Or is there any other technique that would be useful in this scenario?